# Broken pipe: Using map from multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I try to use multiprocessing in HPC to speed up my code. It was running ok, but I added some calculations and suddenly it started to post this error. I ran it without multiprocessing and it was fine.

The first ~20 function executions go well with multiprocessing, but after that it starts snowballing and this error shows up more and more often.

In log it is written that "Exceeded step memory limit at some point" and " Reason: 'RuntimeError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object',)'"

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def eigencen(filename):
    --DO complicated stuff here--

for f in os.listdir(FOLDER):
    list_fn.extend([f])

def evaluation(f_list):
    return list(Pool(processes=28).map(eigencen, f_list))
evaluation(list_fn)
```

Can I fix it somehow? Without multiprocessing it will take forever to run.

Comment: Is the task in question CPU intensive? If not you can use threads instead.

Comment: It is quite memory consuming. I run it on one node with 28 cores, and I think somehow the memory doesn't empty for the next process after finishing one. This is just my guess.

Comment: In that case you can use the multiprocessing module in conjunction with Queues. In general, using queues is much more flexible in terms of controlling your pool processes. Another idea that comes to mind is to use the concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor class that also has map function.

Comment: Are you returning back a complex/huge data set from `eigencen`?

Comment: yes, it is a list with approx 1k values and I run this function for 130 datasets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the `concurrent.futures` module:

```
from concurrent import futures

def evaluation(f_list):
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
        return pool.map(eigencen, f_list)
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! I guess something was wrong with multiprocessing task partition.